# Checking all elements of array for a logical condition in fortran

Tags: gcc, fortran, gfortran

I want to check all rows of an array for a logical condition. I used function `ALL` as described in GNU GCC guide https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/ALL.html

Here is a sample code:

```
program test3
implicit none
real, allocatable, dimension (:,:) :: mat1
integer :: i,j,k,r
logical :: lg
r=3
allocate(mat1(r,r))
mat1=transpose( reshape( (/-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9/), (/3,3/)))
lg=all (abs(mat1)<10,1)
write (*,*) lg
end program
```

In this program, I want to check whether absolute value of all elements along all rows is less than 10. But I am getting error

```
lg=all (abs(mat1)<10,1)
Error: Incompatible ranks 0 and 1 in assignment
```

Any idea about this error or how to do this check?

Comment: You want, for each row that logical test?  That is, you want one logical result for each row of `mat1`?  Three, rather than one, results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Error: Incompatible ranks 0 and 1 in assignment
```

means that you are trying to assign a rank-1 array to a scalar variable.

In this case `lg` is your scalar left-hand side.  As you want to test the condition against each row (as supported by using the `[dim=]1` specifier) it makes sense for `lg` to be an array of rank-1 with as many elements as there are rows in `mat1`.

That said, because Fortran uses column-major storage using `ALL(...,dim=1)` here is actually giving you the test result along columns.  In general, the result of `ALL(L, dim=n)` is of shape `[d_1, d_2, ..., d_{n-1}, d_{n+1}, ..., d_m]` where the shape of `L` is `[d_1, ..., d_m]`.

[As noted in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30834331) the result of `ALL(L)` is a scalar.  If this is what you want here, then I may have something to say about potential confusion with the language of the formal description of `ALL`.]

Answer (score 2):

Use this to get scalar logical:

```
lg = all(abs(mat1) < 10)
```

Comment: Does this answer give a complete solution to the question? If not, it should probably be a comment.

Comment: @NickVolynkin This is a complete answer. The question contains a link to the documentation, so no additional explanation is necessary. The documentation is clear enough: "ALL(MASK) returns a scalar value of type LOGICAL... If DIM is present, then ALL(MASK, DIM) returns an array". Since the question is about testing all the elements, the scalar form is a solution.